# type error in react-router-dom and react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, typescript-typings, react-router-dom

I am a beginner in react with typescript, facing issue in following code

Here is the code of dashboard component

```
export default function Dashboard() {
return(
  <p>Dashboard page</p>
 )
 }
```

Here is code of route

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={"/dashboard" } component={Dashboard} />

          <Route path="/" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

In route code I am facing type issue i.e.

> TypeScript error in E:/Web/src/router/route.tsx(18,51):

No overload matches this call.

Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): Route',
gave the following error. Type '{ Dashboard: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass | FunctionComponent | ComponentClass, any> | FunctionComponent<...> | undefined'.

Type '{ Dashboard: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent>'. Type '{ Dashboard: string; }' provides no match for the signature '(props: PropsWithChildren>, context?: any): ReactElement<...> | null'.

Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouteProps, context?: any): Route', gave the following error.
Type '{ Dashboard: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass |FunctionComponent | ComponentClass, any> | FunctionComponent<...> | undefined'.

Type '{ Dashboard: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent>'.  TS2769

```
16 |       <div>
17 |         <Switch>
```

> 18 |           
>          |                                                   ^
>   "

Comment: Did you import React from ‘react’ in both files?

Comment: Yes I imported react in both files

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't given your components a type (`dashboard` and `login`).

You need to do something similar to the below component declaration image, where by you set the type of your component as `React.FC` after importing the React library. (The FC standing for Functional Component, since we are not using a class-based component model)

#### Component Image

[image]